# Как вывести значения из двух инпутов?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как вывести текст из двух инпутов одновременно, а так же его одновременно очистить после нажатия на button?

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick = btnSend;

    function btnSend(){
        let a = document.querySelector(".i-1");
        let b = document.querySelector(".i-2");
        document.querySelector(".out").innerHTML = a.value;
        a.value = "";
        document.querySelector(".out").innerHTML = b.value;
        b.value = "";
    }
```

```html
  <div class="out">
        <p>тут будет текст</p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-test">
        <input type="text" class="i-2" placeholder="введите ваше имя">
        <input type="text" class="i-1" placeholder="введите ваше сообщение">
        <button>отправить</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте `document.querySelector(".out").innerHTML = a.value + b.value;` вместо отдельных строк, ибо innerHTML замещает текст целиком и в вашем примере будет сохраняться значение только второго инпута.

Comment: Спасибо большое за разъяснение. Сейчас попробую

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick = btnSend;

    function btnSend(){
        let a = document.querySelector(".i-1");
        let b = document.querySelector(".i-2");
        document.querySelector(".out").innerHTML = `Имя: ${a.value}, сообщение: ${b.value}`;
        a.value = "";        
        b.value = "";
    }
```

```html
<div class="out">
        <p>тут будет текст</p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-test">
        <input type="text" class="i-2" placeholder="введите ваше имя">
        <input type="text" class="i-1" placeholder="введите ваше сообщение">
        <button>отправить</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое!